# Running artisan command from controller or route

Tags: laravel, command, backup, laravel-artisan, laravel-backup

I use Spatie Laravel package I can take backup by running this command

```
php artisan backup:run
```

but I want to take back up form admin panel and running this command form controller, I create a route and controller and in the controller, I do this

```
public function backup(){
    \Artisan::call('backup:run');
    return "successfully!";
}
```

when I route to this finally I got the success message but in the backup file, nothing added.

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov No I hot the return message

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup this library uses the same logic I think maybe you can check it out

Comment: @AnarBayramov I use that and I can take a backup file.But I want to take this back up from control panel each time that admin want

Comment: @AnarBayramov and also I get this structure from Laravel docs but I don't now why nothing happen.

Comment: try to definite absolute path maybe it saves to somewhere you dont know

Comment: How I should define it?

Comment: Man did you even read answers?

Comment: this doesn't only occur with this package, I was trying to backup my db without using this package. I made my own command using `exec()` and it works in CLI, however when it is called from controller/route nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You can put artisan command in sheduler. It will make back up for example every day at the same time. You do it in `app/console/Kernel.php`

```
$schedule->command('backup:run')->daily();
```

Remember to set your server for cron jobs:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling