# Laravel: Calling Artisan command from controller not working properly

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to backup my db when I hit a spesific route.
first I made artisan command: `php artisan backupDB`
here is the function:

```
    echo "Generating backup file..\n";
    $filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . ".sql";
    $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . " > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
    
    $returnVar = NULL;
    $output  = NULL;
    
    exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
    echo "Backup file path: ".storage_path() . "/app/backup/".$filename;
```

I run it in cli and it is working fine.
then when I tried to run it via controller:

```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

  public function backupDB{
     Artisan::call("backupDB");
  }
```

when I hit the route it prints the echo, but nothing else happened. just that.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution. wrap the command inside a job or just put the code inside that job, and then start the queue. By doing that the code works fine when I try to hit the route.

```
 php artisan make:job backupDB
```

it will create a file inside app>jobs folder
then put the code inside `handle()` function.

next just call the job inside your controller or route

```
use App\Jobs\backupDB;

public function backup()
{
    $process = new pull();
    dispatch($process);
}
```

and you need to setup the queue, here is the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. Just use [this extension](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup).

PS: I can't explain the problem you are facing, because you didn't provide any debug info: logs, backtrace, or smth like that.

PS2: Be careful with `exec()` functions usage

Comment: I need to backup my data via controller or route. When i used the extension it worked great in cli, but again nothing happened when you called it from controller or route. the same problem also happened in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789532/running-artisan-command-from-controller-or-route)